# Combine or Separate Tables

Tags: database-design, table

I have a single table that holds the following data columns:

**id** = Auto Increment 
**provider** = Twitter or Facebook (depends what they use to login with) 
**uid** = User ID 
**name** = Their full name (e.g. Chris Burton)
**image** = Profile Image 
**link** = Social network profile link

In that same table I also have the following columns

**comment** = Comment text 
**article_id** = Article ID 
**date** = Date of when comment was submitted

My question is, should I keep the user login data separate from my comment data? Or is it more efficient to keep it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separete tables. If one user can make comments on many articles you will have huge repeat of same information.

Comment: Good point. I think what I'll do is only insert the `uid` (User ID) for actual comments. This way I can keep a record of who is posting.